# Using javamail to send from hotmail?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I've got gmail and yahoo working, but not hotmail. Here's what I have, what am I doing wrong?

```
private String mailhost = "smtp.live.com";

    public hotmailSenderActivity(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

  //This connects to the actual mailserver
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());
    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
```

I have tried port 25 + 587 without the SSL stuff. I have tried port 465 WITH the SSL stuff. The email and password are correct (Ive hard coded them to be sure).

I don't receive any errors... So whats the problem?

Comment: did you find this code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Yes, and like I said, it worked wonderfully for gmail and yahoo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) use debug output:

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

2) hotmail smtp server starts non-ssl connection on port 25 or 587, and uses starttls after initial connection; thus remove lines

<strike>props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");

     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");</strike>

3) mimimum amount of settings is then:

```
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

this assumes port is 25, otherwise add props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

4) yet even nicer looks this:

```
    ...
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
    trans.connect("smtp.live.com", 25, "user", "pass");
```

now you're connected, use methods of [Transport](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Transport.html)

Comment: Ahaaa! You've just removed 35% of the stress from my life.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hotmail

Get rid of all that socket factory stuff, you don't need it.

Comment: Anything else I need to get rid of? 

Didn't change anything when I removed those.

Comment: Did you read the FAQ?  It'll tell you what to do when things don't work.

Comment: Ok, and again, the FAQ tells you what to do what things don't work.  One of the things it tells you to do is to run with session debugging turned on and post the protocol trace.  Did you try that?  That might actually provide the information we need to help you.