# How to test that the mail server is alive with Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Is there a way with JavaMail API to check that the mail server used is alive ?
If not, how do to it with Java code ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Define "mail server is alive" state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've got a reference to a [Session](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html) instance, you could do the following:

```
Session s = //a JavaMail session I got from somewhere
boolean isConnected = s.getTransport("smtp").isConnected();
```

If the mail client is connected to the appropriate SMTP server, it usually means it's alive.

Comment: in case you just created a new session and want to call `isConnected()`, initially, you have to call the method `getTransport("smtp").connect()`.

Answer (score 5):

From the JavaMail API, you could try sending an email and seeing if it was sent successfully.

From a connectivity standpoint, you could just ping it:

```
  InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("mailserver");
  System.out.println("host.isReachable(1000) = " + host.isReachable(1000));
```

Comment: Ok, so you confirm that the first solution is the only one : a server does not need to responde to ping to work correctly.

Comment: @DenisR. Correct, a server may very well ignore ICMP echo requests.

Comment: It's not really the only possible solution. SMTP servers may very well ignore ICMP echo requests, but they don't ignore TCP connections to port 25.

Answer (score 1):

From this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086420/using-javamail-to-send-from-hotmail); you can use the following logic:

```
public boolean isAlive() throws MessagingException {
  session.setDebug(true);
  Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
  transport.connect();
  if (transport.isConnected()) {
    transport.close();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```