# Sending HtmlEmail to live.com is failing

Tags: java, apache-commons

I would like to use Apache Commons Email for sending emails through live.com SMTP.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

email.setStartTLSRequired(true); // ???
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true); //???
email.setHostName("smtp.live.com");
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setSslSmtpPort("587");
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);

email.setSubject("subject");
email.setTo("to@email.com");
email.setFrom("from@email.com");
email.setHtmlMsg("body");
```

This code fails:

```
    org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.live.com:587
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1398)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1423)
        at models.helpers.EmailHelper.sendEmail(EmailHelper.java:70)
        at models.helpers.EmailHelper.sendEmail(EmailHelper.java:58)
        at models.entities.Reservation.confirm(Reservation.java:83)
        at models.entities.ReservationTest$1.run(ReservationTest.java:20)
        at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:367)
        at models.entities.ReservationTest.testConfirm(ReservationTest.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 587;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1388)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:541)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:374)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:207)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
        ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hotmail smtp server starts non-ssl connection on port 25 or 587, and uses starttls after initial connection; thus disable ssl.
See more [Using javamail to send from hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086420/using-javamail-to-send-from-hotmail)