# Sending mail from yahoo id to other email ids using Javamail API

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail, yahoo-mail

I am not able to send email from my yahoo id using Java mail API. I tried different options from Google,but fails. Please have a look my below code and let me know if I am missing something. In my point of view ***Yahoo*** does not provide the free service to send mails, but I am not sure. Please provide your thoughts on this.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MailExample {
    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 587;//465,587,25
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "dummyrls@yahoo.com";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "my password";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       new MailExample().test();
    }

    public void test() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");
        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress("rlss@abc.com"));

        transport.connect
          (SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

        transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine for Gmail, but for Yahoo it's giving error like:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1 DEBUG: getProvider() 
  returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,
  Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, 
  useAuth true 
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 587, 
  isSSL false Exception in thread "main" 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP 
  host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587;   nested exception is:  
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)  
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)  
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)     
at com.sample.mailexample.MailExample.test(MailExample.java:313)    
at com.sample.mailexample.MailExample.main(MailExample.java:291) Caused by: 
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect     
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)   
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)    
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)     
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)    
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)  
... 4 more
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Then for nauta as it would be Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server
Servidor SMTP: smtp.nauta.cu, port: 25, Authentication (SI) [In email app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0KFu.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class SendMail {

    String host, port, emailid,username, password;
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session l_session = null;

    public BSendMail() {
        host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        port = "587";
        emailid = "a@yahoo.com";
        username = "a";
        password = "pwd";

        emailSettings();
        createSession();
        sendMessage("a@yahoo.com", "rahul@gmail.com","Test","test Mail");
    }

    public void emailSettings() {
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    }

    public void createSession() {

        l_session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        l_session.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode

    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String emailFromUser, String toEmail, String subject, String msg) {
        //System.out.println("Inside sendMessage 2 :: >> ");
        try {
            //System.out.println("Sending Message *********************************** ");
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(l_session);
            emailid = emailFromUser;
            //System.out.println("mail id in property ============= >>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + emailid);
            //message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailid));
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.emailid));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(AppConstants.fromEmail));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html");

            //message.setText(msg);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message Sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end catch block
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, Morning it was working fine, but now it is giving me the following error: Any idea why this is coming, please let me know. `DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 587, isSSL false
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587;`

Comment: Everything above is correct except the port number (not 587) but 465. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The complete code to send email from Yahoo using JavaMail API as below:

```
package ripon.java.mail;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendFromYahoo
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{    
    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
     String from = "test123@yahoo.com";
     String pass ="test123";
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "riponalwasim@yahoo.com";
   String host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";

   // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();
   // Setup mail server
   properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

   // Get the default Session object.
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   try{
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

      // Set From: header field of the header.
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

      // Set To: header field of the header.
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));

      // Set Subject: header field
      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

      // Now set the actual message
      message.setText("This is actual message");

      // Send message
      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
      transport.connect(host, from, pass);
      transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
      transport.close();
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! BTW one can remove `props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); props.put("mail.smtp.user", user); props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass)` and simply mention that in `transport.connect(host, port, user, pass);` and it should work identically.

Comment: Failing with the error:

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Transaction failed :  Cannot send message due to possible abuse; please visit http://postmaster.yahoo.com/abuse_smtp.html for more information

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1889)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
 at SendFromYahoo.main(SendFromYahoo.java:46)