# Java Send Mail Using yahoo

Tags: java, email, smtp

This is my code

```
public class MailSend
{

    String host, port, emailid,username, password;
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session l_session = null;
    private static final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";  
    public MailSend() {
    host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    port = "587";
    username = "xxxx@yahoo.com";
    password = "xxxxxx";

}
public String sendMail(String toaddress,String subj,String msg)
{
    emailSettings();
    createSession();
   String res= sendMessage("xxxx@yahoo.com", toaddress,subj,msg);
   return res;
}
public void emailSettings() {
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);  

}

public void createSession() {

    l_session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx@yahoo.com", "xxxxx");
                }
            });

    l_session.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode

}

public  String sendMessage(String emailFromUser, String toEmail, String subject, String msg) {

    try {

        Address addr = new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress("xxxxx@yahoo.com","xxxx@yahoo.com");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(l_session);
        emailid = emailFromUser;
        message.setFrom(addr);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail Sent");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch block
    return "success";
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    MailSend m=new MailSend();
    m.sendMail("xxxxxxx@yahoo.com", "welcome", "testing");
}
```

when i run this code i got the following exception

```
 **com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required** Exception.
```

but i'm using `PasswordAuthenticator`.
I don't know why this exception coming.can any one tell how to resolve this exception or please give any reference site.

Comment: You can find the answer at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356237/sending-mail-from-yahoo-id-to-other-email-ids-using-javamail-api][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356237/sending-mail-from-yahoo-id-to-other-email-ids-using-javamail-api