# Message-ID header of Yahoo mail

Tags: email, header, email-headers

Usually the *Message-ID* header from a specific sender that uses a yahoo email account is like this:

```
Message-ID: <1415953854.62001.YahooMailNeo@web172504.mail.ir2.yahoo.com>
```

And comes along with the *X-Mailer* header

```
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.203.733
```

But sometimes the email headers of the same sender may include a different *Message-ID* header:

```
Message-ID: <763084588.2169028.1420389380369.JavaMail.yahoo@jws11101g.mail.ir2.yahoo.com>
```

In which cases there is no *X-Mailer* header.

[Here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Mail_Header_Format) it says that the *Message-ID* header of the first case (...**YahooMailNeo**...) indicates it was sent via Yahoo Webmail from Chrome.

So does anybody know which interface does **JavaMail.yahoo** of the second case indicate?

Comment: I'm guessing it comes from an API.

Comment: Yes I know that there exists a JavaMail API but I'm trying to find out which application/interface the sender used in this case.

Comment: The JavaMail API _is_ the interface the sender used. Are you looking for something like the domain of the client application?

Comment: I want to know which email client he used (web-based or not). I suppose that this Message-ID indicates an email client that uses the JavaMail API, but which client is that?

Comment: he didn't use an email client. He used some random application that uses the API.

Comment: I don't understand. What "random" application uses the JavaMail API? In the first case we know that he used Yahoo Webmail from Chrome (according to the link).

Comment: Anyone who wants to can write an application that uses an API.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356237/sending-mail-from-yahoo-id-to-other-email-ids-using-javamail-api for example. The poster wrote their own application that uses the JavaMail API.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but this mail comes from a person who is not a programmer and is certainly using an email client. This is why I'm asking, I supposed that "JavaMail.yahoo" in the Message-ID indicates a specific client.

Comment: I don't think it means a specific client. He's just using some client that happens to use the JavaMail API.