# How to send Java email using smtp.mail.yahoo.com?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails from "smtp.mail.yahoo.com". I have tried using different port numbers like 587, 465 etc., It works fine when I send using gmail host. But when i try using yahoo, I am getting the below exception.

```
package com.java.sample.workouts;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JavaSendEmail {

private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "myyahooid@yahoo.com";
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "mypassword";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   new JavaSendEmail().test();
}

public void test() throws Exception{
    Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");        
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);
                }
              });

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myyahooid@yahoo.com"));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         new InternetAddress("myyahooid@yahoo.com"));

    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message,
        message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
}
```

}

But I am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.1 Authentication failed

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:823)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:673)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at com.java.sample.workouts.JavaSendEmail.test(JavaSendEmail.java:46)
at com.java.sample.workouts.JavaSendEmail.main(JavaSendEmail.java:18)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356237/sending-mail-from-yahoo-id-to-other-email-ids-using-javamail-api have you seen this?

Comment: Yes I tried that. But still i am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps to enable Less Secure Apps in your Yahoo account:

1. Go to Account Info
2. Select “Account Security”
3. Enable “Allow Apps that use less secure
       sign in”

I just tested your code and it's working

Comment: @Kutty As you can see, Yahoo cast Java Mail Client as less secured.

Comment: I am getting "535 Authentication failed" for the host  "smtpout.secureserver.net"; Can you please help me in resolving this ?

Comment: @Kutty Set session.setDebug(true), run again and give me the output