# Email sending hangs in Spring with Java Mail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a simple mail using spring.

Here is my mail sender bean definition in java configuration.

```
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setSession(getMailSession());
        return mailSender;
    }

    public Session getMailSession() {
        JndiTemplate template = new JndiTemplate();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = (Session) template.lookup("java:jboss/mail/Default");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return session;
    }
```

I'm running is jboss wildfly and the beans are created without any issue.

Here is my code to send the email.

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Override
public void sendMail(String mailTo, String subject, String content) throws MessagingException{
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mailTo,false));
    mailSender.send(message);  
}
```

the JavaMailSender is injected correctly. when I debug the execution happens till `mailsender.send()` method. and it starts to hang.

It seems all the configurations in the jboss is correct. I also tried specifying the mail server parameters in the bean it self. but still it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your mail session correctly configured in JBoss? Is the SMTP server up and running, can you actually connect to the server from JBoss. Looks like a mail session configuration problem to me.

Comment: i'm using gmail smtp. and i can telnet and connect to it. this is what i used : telent smtp.gmail.com 465

Comment: this is my jboss configuration : <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="smtp.gmail.com">
                    <login name="username" password="password"/>
                </smtp-server>
            </mail-session>
 </subsystem>

<outbound-socket-binding name="smtp.gmail.com">
            <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>

Comment: after 10 mins of hanging it throws the exception : Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

Comment: the expection clearly tells that the smtp is refusing the connection at the port. I hope you should test it at port 587

Comment: A similar question has been answered at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597616/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-java

Comment: Hi thanks for the info guys. i tried going through them but still couldnt get my issue sorted. as one has suggested in a post i added the session.debut(true). and i got this error.  javax.mail.MessagingException: No MimeMessage content. i tried using the SimpleMailMessage and sending the email but the same result.

Comment: Guys got it sorted my silly mistake i have being trying to sent the email with a null content. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Though the issue is already resolved, I faced similar issue, and none of the steps mentioned above and on other threads worked. I had to additionally specify the protocol as SMTPS for this to work. So here is my working code snippet.

```
    @Bean
  JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(props.getHost());
    mailSender.setPort(props.getPort());
    mailSender.setUsername(props.getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(props.getPassword());

    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", props.getSmtp().isAuth());
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", props.getSmtp().isStarttlsEnable());
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    mailSender.setProtocol("smtps");

    return mailSender;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions to send an email with Spring and Gmail: [Email with Spring and Gmail](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/)

You're completely missing the authentication part. And make sure the Gmail smtp server address is correct.

Taken from the above link these must be the configurations;

```
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
           </props>
    </property>
```