# Can't send command to SMTP host

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am not able to send mail. I have tried in multiple way. but still I am getting exception. I am pasting stacktrace and my code over here. Thank you in advance.
I am sending test mail from rest ful api.
This is my mail code.

```
@Controller
public class TestSendMail {

    @RequestMapping(value = "Customer/mailcheck.htm")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMail(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception, JSONException {

        String to = "shah201999@gmail.com";
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final String from = "skent.qc@gmail.com";
        final String password = "12345";//change accordingly
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("Sent by ashish shah from live , this is sample for to check send " +
                    "email using JavaMailAPI ");
            Transport.send(message);
            jsonObject.put("Status", "Success");

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            jsonObject.put("Status", "Error" + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        jsonarray.put(jsonObject);
        return jsonarray.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is stackTrace.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path 
>       [/HomZservice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception 
>       is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send
>       command to SMTP host;
>       nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during
>       handshake] with root cause
>       java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:101)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1418)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
>       at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
>       at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
>       at
>       com.houzservice.admin.controller.TestSendMail.testMail(TestSendMail.java:78)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
>       at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Google for smtp.gmail.com settings, it does not use port 25

Comment: Thanks but I have check 587 as well. still getting exception. Nambari

Comment: 576 is tls try 465 for ssl

Comment: Thank you for the response. @Alex K. but i want to send through SMTP and its port either 587 or 25.. so where i have to set 465 port for ssl. Please guide.

Comment: No, its port is not 25: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en see [Sending Email via gmail smtp server in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597616/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-java)