# Webdriver script to send email notification and consolidate data in excel

Tags: selenium, webdriver, reporting

I am writing a webdriver automation to find if last comment of a bug in JIRA has my teams name or id and if so I will have to send individual emails to them to look into that comment and also have to send consolidated list of resource name, bug id  and comment to my manager automatically in an Excel file

So far I had a workbook where I have all my team members id and name and also have JIRA URL, username and password in that workbook 
Below is the progress of the script where I print all required in console output. Need help in email sending part and consolidating results in Excel

```html
package myproject;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.*;
//import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import java.lang.*;
public class jiracomments {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
           String url, name, password;
           String[] database = new String[30];
           String[] id = new String[30];   
           String FilePath = "mypath";
           FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
           Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

           // TO get the access to the sheet
           Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
    
           url = sh.getCell(2,0).getContents();
           System.out.println("JQL applied is : "+url);
           name = sh.getCell(2,1).getContents();
           System.out.println("Logged in with username: "+ name);
           password = sh.getCell(2,2).getContents();
                 
           try{
               for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++) {
                   database[row]=sh.getCell(0, row).getContents();
               }
           }
           catch(Exception i){}
           try{
               for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++) {
                   id[row]=sh.getCell(1, row).getContents();
               }
           }
           catch(Exception i){}
           int v,i, x, xp;
           boolean b;
           String[] bug = new String[30];
           String[] jiraname = new String[30];                
           WebDriver driver;
           // System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://Users/rajamas/Desktop/Selenium Jars/geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64/");
           driver =new FirefoxDriver();
               
           driver.get(url);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div/div/section/form/div[1]/fieldset/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(name);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div/div/section/form/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(password);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div/div/section/form/div[2]/div/input")).click();

           //Number of results in filter
           String counter= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[3]")).getText();
           int rows_count=Integer.parseInt(counter);       
           Thread.sleep(30000);
           //to sort comments section
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='issuetable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]")).click();
           Thread.sleep(10000);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='activitymodule']/div[2]/div[1]/div/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='return-to-search']")).click();
            System.out.println("Comments having DA's id is : "+rows_count);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Below list has DA's id in last comment: ");
            System.out.println("");
            //to loop through all Jira's
            for (int row=1;row<=rows_count;row++){
                System.out.println(row);
                // to navigate to next page if more than 100 results 
                if (row == 101) {
                    row=row-100;
                 rows_count=rows_count-100;
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/a[2]")).click();
                 System.out.println("Moving to next page");
                 Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
             String row1= Integer.toString(row);
             //to get bug id and click and navigate to bug details page
             String bugId = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='issuetable']/tbody/tr["+row1+"]/td[1]/a[2]")).getText();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='issuetable']/tbody/tr["+row1+"]/td[1]/a[2]")).click();
             Thread.sleep(30000);               
             // to get the last comments value
             String newsting= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='activitymodule']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();
             //code to be added to either send an email if DA name is available or raise nc
             for (int count=0;count<28;count++)
             {
                    if(newsting.toLowerCase().indexOf(id[count].toLowerCase())!=-1){
                    System.out.println("YOU HAVE AN ALERT: "+id[count]+" PLEASE LOOK INTO BUG: "+bugId);
              System.out.println("The comment in your name is : "+newsting);
              System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            // to go back to search results
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='return-to-search']")).click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending email entails interacting with the mail server. Nice description of how to integrate that into [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597616/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-java) is found here.