# haxe send email smtp

Tags: email, haxe, openfl

I am trying to send an email through my app and have been looking at mtwin Smpt. After entering all my my login info I get this error:

```
Error : SmtpAuthError(Authorization with 'login' method not supported by server)

mtwin.mail.Smtp.send( smtp.googlemail.com, 'xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx@xxx.com', 'My Message',587,'xxx@gmail.com','xxxxxxx' );
```

Using the SmtpMailer mailer library has similar issues. SmtpMailer gives you the option to specify SSL/STARTLS but I get the error

```
Not supported on this platform
```

I am targeting Mac and Windows.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a different mailing library, as Google will only accept secure connections. Why not [javax.mail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15598232/1790644).

Comment: What Haxe target are you using? C++, Neko, Java?

Comment: My Target is C++

Comment: C++ should have a working TLS stack out of the box (I think), at least on recent Haxe releases.  Any chance you're using something pre 3.4?

Comment: Currently on 3.4.0

Comment: @Frank, I'm glad the issue was [solved](https://github.com/benmerckx/smtpmailer/issues/1) in SmtpMailer.

Comment: You know, you can answer (and later accept) your own questions here in StackOverflow?  I leave this to you, so that you earn the reputation...  it was you who reported the issue and ultimately got it to be fixed.